# Derived categories of modules categories

Tags: reference-request, derived-categories, modules

Does anyone know if there is a note or a paper about the derived category of the category $\sigma[M]$ where $M$ is a left module over a ring?, and some uses of this.

Comment: What is $\sigma[M]$?

Comment: Sorry i'll try to be more specific $\sigma[M]$ denotes the full subcategory of a module category, of modules subgenerated by $M$, that is, $N\in\sigma[M]$ if and only there is a set $I$ for which $N$ is a submodule of a quotient $M^{(I)}/K$ for some $K$, an example of this, consider any associative ring with unit $R$, then $\sigma[R]=R-Mod$.